# Cannot Open The Outlook Window - after upgrade

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I have been trying to upgrade a colleagues email from Outlook 2007 / Exchange Server 2007 to Outlook 2010 / Exchange 2010, however I am unable to get Outlook 2010 to open following the change.

I exported all the users email to a file, then uninstalled office 2007. On the server side, I deleted the existing email account, then re-created it in Exchange 2010 via our webhosts portal (Fasthosts).

I have now installed Office 2010 on the machine and I am trying to configure the users email. Via Control Panel - > Mail I have entered the correct connection details (I have compared them to my own machine, which connects fine). After entering the correct details, I am prompted for a password, after which the Add Account wizard closes, suggesting it is happy with the settings.

On opening Outlook however, I receive the following error:

> Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. Cannot open the Outlook window. The set of folders cannot be opened. You must connect to Microsoft Exchange with the current profile before you can synchronze your folders with your Outlook data file (.ost).

Previously the user had two data files configured in outlook, one for his inbox and one for archived emails. After the upgrade the archived data file re-attached itself and was causing outlook to continually prompt for a password (rejecting the correct password, which was changed after the upgrade as user couldnt remember his previous password). Removing the data file caused it to stop prompting for the password and instead throw up the current error.

Any thoughts on this?